# How to connect Metabase to Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, metabase

Following [this](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/administration-guide/databases/bigquery.html) tutorial or [this](https://www.stitchdata.com/blog/tutorial-metabase-with-data-warehouse-for-analytics/), an oAuth clientId and clientSecret is required from Google in order to connect metabase to BigQuery service.

```
Make sure to choose 'Other' for your application type.
```

Google doesn't have application type "other" in its selection anymore.

Is there a workaround for this limitation?

Comment: I just tested and used the "Desktop Application" and it worked fine. Try that.